# How to set up Viewmodel class properly?

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

I'm trying to follow some tutotial from github about MVVM model and i'm stuck at viewmodel class because there's an error says

```
Not enough information to infer type variable T
```

and

```
Type mismatch.
Required:Resource<Movie>
Found:Unit
```

And when i check my other class like ApiService, Dao, NetworkBoundResource, ApiResponse, Resources and respository everthing fine like this

ApiService :

```
interface ApiService {
    @GET("3/movie/popular")
    fun getMyMovie(@Query("api_key") api : String = "32bbbffe944d16d1d2a3ee46cfc6aaa0"
    ) : Flow<ApiResponse<MovieResponse.Movie>>
}
```

MovieDao:

```
@Dao
interface MovieDao : BaseDao<Movie> {

//    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
//    fun insertMovie(movie: List<Movie>)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM `movie` ORDER by movie_id DESC")
    fun getMyMovie() : Flow<Movie>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM `movie` ORDER by movie_id DESC")
    fun findAllMovie() : Maybe<List<Movie>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM `movie` ORDER by movie_id DESC")
    fun streamAll() : Flowable<List<Movie>>

    @Query("DELETE FROM `movie`")
    fun deleteAll()
}
```

MovieRespository:

```
class MovieRespository (val apiService: ApiService, val movieDao: MovieDao) {

    fun getListMovie() : Flow<Resource<Movie>> {
        return networkBoundResource(
                fetchFromLocal = { movieDao.getMyMovie() },
                shouldFetchFromRemote = {true},
                fetchFromRemote = {apiService.getMyMovie()},
                processRemoteResponse = {},
                saveRemoteData = {movieDao.insert(
                        it.results.let {
                            it.map { data -> Movie.from(data) }
                        }
                )},
                onFetchFailed = {_, _ ->}
        ).flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
    }
```

NeteorkBoundResource:

```
inline fun <DB, REMOTE> networkBoundResource(
        crossinline fetchFromLocal: () -> Flow<DB>,
        crossinline shouldFetchFromRemote: (DB?) -> Boolean = { true },
        crossinline fetchFromRemote: () -> Flow<ApiResponse<REMOTE>>,
        crossinline processRemoteResponse: (response: ApiSuccessResponse<REMOTE>) -> Unit = { Unit },
        crossinline saveRemoteData: (REMOTE) -> Unit = { Unit },
        crossinline onFetchFailed: (errorBody: String?, statusCode: Int) -> Unit = { _: String?, _: Int -> Unit }
) = flow<Resource<DB>> {

    emit(Resource.Loading(null))

    val localData = fetchFromLocal().first()

    if (shouldFetchFromRemote(localData)) {

        emit(Resource.Loading(localData))

        fetchFromRemote().collect { apiResponse ->
            when (apiResponse) {
                is ApiSuccessResponse -> {
                    processRemoteResponse(apiResponse)
                    apiResponse.body?.let { saveRemoteData(it) }
                    emitAll(fetchFromLocal().map { dbData ->
                        Resource.Success(dbData)
                    })
                }

                is ApiErrorResponse -> {
                    onFetchFailed(apiResponse.errorMessage, apiResponse.statusCode)
                    emitAll(fetchFromLocal().map {
                        Resource.Error(
                                apiResponse.errorMessage,
                                it
                        )
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        emitAll(fetchFromLocal().map { Resource.Success(it) })
    }
}
```

ApiResponse:

```
sealed class ApiResponse<T> {
    companion object {

        fun <T> create(error: Throwable): ApiErrorResponse<T> {
            return ApiErrorResponse(
                    error.message ?: "Unknown error",
                    0
            )
        }


        fun <T> create(response: Response<T>): ApiResponse<T> {
            return if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val body = response.body()
                val headers = response.headers()
                if (body == null || response.code() == 204) {
                    ApiEmptyResponse()
                } else {
                    ApiSuccessResponse(
                            body,
                            headers
                    )
                }
            } else {
                val msg = response.errorBody()?.string()
                val errorMsg = if (msg.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    response.message()
                } else {
                    msg
                }
                ApiErrorResponse(
                        errorMsg ?: "Unknown error",
                        response.code()
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * separate class for HTTP 204 responses so that we can make ApiSuccessResponse's body non-null.
 */
class ApiEmptyResponse<T> : ApiResponse<T>()

data class ApiSuccessResponse<T>(
        val body: T?,
        val headers: okhttp3.Headers
) : ApiResponse<T>()

data class ApiErrorResponse<T>(val errorMessage: String, val statusCode: Int) : ApiResponse<T>()
```

Resource:

```
data class Resource<out T>(val status: Status, val data: T?, val message: String?) {

//    data class Loading<T>(val loadingData: T?) : Resource<T>(Status.LOADING, loadingData, null)
//    data class Success<T>(val successData: T?) : Resource<T>(Status.SUCCESS, successData, null)
//    data class Error<T>(val msg: String, val error: T?) : Resource<T>(Status.ERROR, error, msg)

    companion object {

        fun <T> Success(data: T?): Resource<T> {
            return Resource(Status.SUCCESS, data,null)
        }

        fun <T> Error(msg: String, data: T? = null): Resource<T> {
            return Resource(Status.ERROR, data, msg)
        }

        fun <T> Loading(data: T? = null): Resource<T> {
            return Resource(Status.LOADING, data, null)

        }
    }
}
```

MainViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel(private val movieRespository: MovieRespository) : ViewModel() {
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    val getListMovies: LiveData<Resource<Movie>> = movieRespository.getListMovie().map {
        when(it.status){
            Resource.Loading() ->{}
            Resource.Success() ->{}
            Resource.Error() ->{}
        }
    }.asLiveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext)
}
```

to be specific this what the error looks like and this is the link of tutorial i learn
https://github.com/hadiyarajesh/flower

[viewModel Class Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8nrt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error, because Inside the `when`, you are trying to construct a new instance of `Resource.Loading()` etc, but those require a type, so it would need to be something like `Resource.Loading<Movie>()`.

Tht being said, you are doing `when(it.status)`, so the cases in the `when`, should not be a `Resource.Loading`, but `Status.LOADING` instead:

```kotlin
class MainViewModel(private val movieRespository: MovieRespository) : ViewModel() {
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    val getListMovies: LiveData<Resource<Movie>> = movieRespository.getListMovie().map {
        when(it.status){
            Status.LOADING ->{}
            Status.SUCCESS ->{}
            Status.ERROR ->{}
        }
        return@map it
    }.asLiveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext)
}
```

Also, since you are declaring `LiveData<Resource<Movie>>`, you need to return a `Resource<Movie>` from the `map {}` (we could drop `return@map`, it is just to be explicit)